# Issue with jquery tablesorter and {sorter: false}

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Seem to be having an issue with the tablesorter plugin and excluding columns for sorting. In the documentation: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-headers.html you can add a class to the th (class="{sorter: false}") so sorting is disabled on that column. This does not seem to work and also his example on that page does not work. If you inspect the source you can see that the class is specified on 2 columns but they are still sortable.

I know this used to work as I have a project which uses it and it works. I am however using an older version of jquery in that project so that is probably the issue. Maybe the meta-data is not compatible with the latest version of jquery?

Is anyone else having this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure why the metadata isn't registering - I have a [working demo here](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-meta-headers.html)

But I wanted to add that I ended up adding a fork of the [tablesorter plugin on github](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/). I've also made it so you can just use a class name instead of relying on metadata, like this `class="sorter-false"` - here is the [demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html).

Comment: Seems that setting sorter to false in any means is not working. It does not work on the documentation page either: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html

Comment: Thanks @zed, that problem has been fixed in v2.30.4 (problem was introduced in v2.30.3).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that there is a 404 error for file "http://tablesorter.com/jquery.metadata.js"
just fix this and it will work.

Comment: Mottie's forked version is handy but this should be the correct answer.